# How to resolve "parameter has incomplete type" error?

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I'm a newbie and I need help with debugging my code.
When I compile it 'type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete' and type of formal parameter 2 is incomplete' error appears in

```
 printf("Age is %d years.\n", calc_age(birth, current));
```

while 'parameter 1 ('birth') has incomplete type' and ' parameter 2 ('current') has incomplete type' errors appear in

```
int calc_age (struct date birth, struct date current) {
```

Help is appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int calc_age (struct date birth, struct date current);


int main(void)
{

    struct date {
        int month[1];
        int day[1];
        int year[1];

};


    struct date birth, current;
    char c;

    printf("Input the birthdate (MM/DD/YY): ");
    scanf("%d %c %d %c %d", birth.month, &c, birth.day, &c, birth.year);
    printf("Input date to calculate (MM/DD/YY): ");
    scanf("%d %c %d %c %d", current.month, &c,  current.day, &c, current.year);

    printf("Age is %d years.\n", calc_age(birth, current));

    return 0;

}

int calc_age (struct date birth, struct date current) {

    int age;

    if (birth.month[0] < current.month[0]) {
        age = (current.year[0] - birth.year[0]);
    } else if (birth.month[0] > current.month[0]) {
        age = (current.year[0] - birth.year[0] - 1);
    } else {
        if (birth.day[0] <= current.day[0]) {
            age = (current.year[0] - birth.year[0]);
        } else {
            age = (current.year[0] - birth.year[0] - 1);
        }
    }

    return age;
}
```

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of items successfully read : test the return value of `scanf()` ! If  it does not print things before the end of the program...Remember that stdout is buffered. Add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("...");` and things wil be displayed at the right time. You may want to add newline  as things are printed : add `\n` at the end of the string printed. Like `printf("...\n",...);`

Comment: define of `struct date` move to before prototype of `calc_age`.

Comment: `int year[1];` is equal to just `int year;`, drop the array syntax if you don't need arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct date {
    int month[1];
    int day[1];
    int year[1];

};

int calc_age (struct date birth, struct date current);


int main(void)
{
struct date birth, current;
char c;

printf("Input the birthdate (MM/DD/YY): ");
scanf("%d %c %d %c %d", birth.month, &c, birth.day, &c, birth.year);
printf("Input date to calculate (MM/DD/YY): ");
scanf("%d %c %d %c %d", current.month, &c,  current.day, &c, current.year);

printf("Age is %d years.\n", calc_age(birth, current));

return 0;

}

int calc_age (struct date birth, struct date current) {
int age;

if (birth.month[0] < current.month[0]) {
    age = (current.year[0] - birth.year[0]);
} else if (birth.month[0] > current.month[0]) {
    age = (current.year[0] - birth.year[0] - 1);
} else {
    if (birth.day[0] <= current.day[0]) {
        age = (current.year[0] - birth.year[0]);
    } else {
        age = (current.year[0] - birth.year[0] - 1);
    }
}

return age;
}
```

You should define the struct before `main`

Answer (score 7):

Your program is showing `incomplete type` error because the scope of `struct date` is limited to `main()` function only. Outside the `main()` the structure definition is not visible.

So, the `struct date` definition should be in global scope so that it is visible from `calc_age()` (and maybe other functions, too). Even better, if you can create and maintain a header file for this purpose.

That said, in your code, as per your current requirement, get rid of single-element arrays in the structure, like

```
struct date {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
 };
```

and also, the `scanf()` statement

```
scanf("%d %c %d %c %d", birth.month, &c, birth.day, &c, birth.year);
```

should read

```
scanf("%d %c %d %c %d", &birth.month, &c, &birth.day, &c, &birth.year);
```

Comment: It's a good point to advice a modification of struct date. Having arrays of size 1 as fields is unusual. I don't know where such a feature would be useful. And function `calc_age()` would be more elegant.