# Passing Structures vs Passing Variables to a Function in C

Tags: c, function, struct, scope, structure

Why should structures be defined outside the main function for other functions to be able to receive them? I understood [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29371892/4179032), but why is it possible for normal variables declared in the main function (e.g. int and float) to be used as arguments for a function but not structures defined in main?

(PS: I asked this question because I still don't have enough reputation to comment!)

Comment: When you say "a structure", are you talking about a type (defined with `struct thingy {...stuff...};`), or are you talking about variables with that type (defined with `struct thingy myThingy;`?)

Comment: I'm referring to functions that receive instances of a structure - i.e. variables with that type.

Comment: so "why can't you pass variables defined in `main` to other functions if they have structure type?"? The answer to that is you can!

Comment: Alternatively, if you're thinking of the *type* being declared inside `main`: The reason for the difference is essentially that `int` and `float` aren't declared inside a function. (Just like struct types declared outside any function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word: "Scope".

If your struct's type is defined is in `main()` then the type's scope is `main`. Nothing outside `main` can know about it. If you want to pass it to another function, obviously that function has to know the type, but if the type is only known in `main` then obviously the function can't know about it.

The solution? Move the type's scope to somewhere that both main and the "receiving" function can see it.

Edit: built in types like `int`, `char` etc already have global scope and so they are known everywhere. What we're dealing with here is a user define type whose scope is limited based on where it is defined.

The same rules apply to variables (aka instances of a type) - a global variable is visible anywhere (I know, you can "hide it" with a local of the same name - lets not split hairs eh ;-), but a local variable in `main()` can only be seen inside `main()`.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know why this works for normal variables defined in main (e.g. int x). Shouldn't their scope also be restricted to main only?

Comment: The reason it works is that other types are _intrinsic_, such as, `char, short, int, long, double, ...` so everybody knows about them

Comment: @Leponzo You're confusing the *type's* scope with the *variable's* scope.

Comment: @Leponzo And it seems you are also mixing up the concept of *variables* and *types*. A base type like `int` is available everywhere. But a variable declared in `main` (or any function) is only available in `main` - regardless of whether the variable is of a base type or a struct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concepts of *scope* and *primitive data types*. Structures are not primitive types but user defined constructs, so if you define a structure in a given scope it will not be known to the program outside of that scope, because it was you who defined it so it is restricted to the scope where you did define it. [Primitive data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) like (`int`, `float`, `char`) defined in the language and are known to the whole program. If they were not available everywhere, it would actually be impossible to define `main()` itself, since

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

This simple definition of `main()` required `int` to be "*defined*" already.

Finally, to be able to define structures you also need these primitive types because you define a structure as an object that contains one or more of these primitives. You can of course use previously defined structures as members to structures and so on.